# How to run a local IIS inside a Web Form project in Visual Studio 2013?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, winforms, visual-studio, asp.net-mvc-3

Is it possible to create a desktop application (with an executable file) through a "Windows Forms" project in Visual Studio 2013?. Also, this application should include a "view" that can deploy another Web solution that I already did using MVC. The final users have no local IIS since and they are not allowed to install IIS in their Windows. Is this possible?

Comment: "desktop application (with an executable file) through a "windows form" project in Visual Studio 2013" - that's exactly what a windows form project is, a desktop application.

Comment: If I understand what I need to know I am how through windows form I add a ready-made solution in MVC and that run without IIS installed ??

Comment: You *are* going to need to have IIS running on the target machine, *or* on a mutually-agreed location at the final deployment site.  You may need to discuss this application requirement **now** with "The Powers That Be."